# Is it possible to call a function or a script with a REST API?

Tags: api, api-design, mobile, multi-platform, backend

Let us say that I want to create a workout app and a website, the user enters his workout stats and the app display his stats with graphs percentage and such.

This is an example I don't want to create a workout app, just to understand how platforms work.

Assuming that I want to have an Android, iOS app and a website. All with the same functionalities.

From what I read, REST APIs are used for back end.
This is an easy way of exchanging data between an app and the database.
But what about operations on the data ?

Let us say I want to compute the average workout time (or something much more complex). Do I have to compute it on the device so create the algorithm 3 times (Android, iOS and web) or run all computations on the server ?

I tried to read the documentation of a REST api (Eve for Python) but I only found data operations like get update and delete.

Does REST APIs provides only data operation, is it possible to call a function or a script with a REST API ?

Maybe I misunderstood everything so could someone explain me how back ends works for a multi device platform ?

Comment: Have you ever created and manipulated a database before?

Comment: Have you ever created a website?

Comment: REST is not a standard, so strictly speaking it is possible to do whatever you want.  People speak of "RESTful" APIs like they speak of good grammar.  The rules are soft, and can be broken.

Comment: Do you want to ask the server "give me the average workout time", or do you want to ask "calculate the average workout time"? The first would be a request that fits the REST ideas very well: You ask for some information and you don't care how or when it gets calculated, as long as the information is accurate.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot about **POST.**

You need to learn a bit more about REST (you actually need to learn a whole bunch of other stuff as well), but suffice it to say that if you want to do any other operation besides a GET, PUT, PATCH or DELETE, it's probably going to be a *POST.*

Also, note that there are other ways to communicate with a server besides REST.  Stand up a WebSocket, and you can pretty much do whatever you want.

In any case, a GET suffices for what you want to do, if you want to stay with REST.

Comment: Calculating an average of values is idempotent and side effect free, so meets the requirements for a GET.

Comment: @PeteKirkham: Yes, that's true.  My answer still holds, however.  I never said he couldn't use a GET.

Answer (score 2):

Is this RESTful?

```
public PlanksTotalController : Controller
{
    public double Get(int reps, TimeSpan duration)
    {
        return reps * duration;
    }
}
```

Maybe, maybe not. I don't really care if it meets the criteria for some ideal architecture. I care that I've created a service that is useful across platforms. I've deduplicated my code base by centralizing it someplace where it's available everywhere I need it to be.

WebAPIs aren't just for storing and retrieving raw data. Nothing says it can't do a calculation.

---

By the way, I do think that so long as your end points are pure functions (given the same input, they'll always return the same output), that they *can* indeed be RESTful. I believe this because a given resource path (`~/PlankTotal?reps=2&duration=3.5`) will always return that specific resource (the number `7`).

Of course, there are other things to consider, like discoverability, when declaring an API to be RESTful, but that's besides the point. Yes, you can (and *should*) centralize business logic in a service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cross-origin resource sharing and send a script as a variable that a script engine evaluates and returns the evaluated function.